# How to pass a coordinate through a locations cell (up/down/left/right): Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

So I've searched on overflow for about 30min now and I can't find anything that I think would've helped me. So here I am.

I'm doing a maze algorithm basically and working on this recursive method but idk if what I'm doing works. Sounds stupid ik...it won't display the maze with the arrows(directions) on my displayer for one, two apparently I need to "pass a coordinate next to it (say, the above cell, for example)" and I need to code it this way somehow. Here is my method.

```
private boolean findPath(char[][] maze, int r, int c) {

// Base Case #1: If Current Cell == 'H'
if(maze[r][c] == 'H') { 
  return true; // Stop Recursion, Conclusion: Path Found from 'G' to 'H'
} 

// Base Case #2: If Current Cell == '#' (Wall)
else if(maze[r][c] == '#') {
  return false; // Stop Recursion, Conclusion: Path NOT Found
}

// Base Case #3: If Current Cell == '.' (Blocked Path/Dead End)
else if(maze[r][c] == '.') {
  return false; // Stop Recursion, Conclusion: Path NOT Found
} 

// Recursive Cases:
if(maze[r][c] == ' ') { // Check If Current Cell == ' '
  maze[r][c] = '^'; // If Yes, Place Symbol
  findPath(maze, r-1, c); // Recursively Go Up
  // code here ???? add missing code??? HELP MEEEE
  if(maze[r][c] == 'H') { // Check If We Have Reached The End
    return true; // If Yes, Return True
  }
}
// Viewing Purposes
    for (int x = 0; x < maze.length; x++) { // Go Through Rows
      display.newLine(); // Viewing Purposes
      for (int y = 0; y < maze[x].length; y++) { // Go Through Columns
        display.writeC(maze[x][y]); // Viewing Purposes
      }
    }
return false; // If End of Method Reached. Therefore, Hansel Hasn't Been Found Yet
}
```

Comment: Hey John, could you elaborate more about what do expect?

Comment: Hey thx for responding so basically im going from point a to point b...i want my point a which i called 'G' to check a bunch of directions and try to move to them if its possible while marking them with an arrow corresponding with the direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very important thing to do when writing a recursive method is if the method returns a value, *make use of the return value returned by the recursive call*. If you are not making use of it, like you are doing here:

```
if(maze[r][c] == ' ') { // Check If Current Cell == ' '
  maze[r][c] = '^'; // If Yes, Place Symbol
  // you are discarding the return value here!
  findPath(maze, r-1, c); // Recursively Go Up
```

Then you are probably going something wrong.

The return value of `findPath` tells you whether a path can be found from a certain position. You can make use of this information. If a path *can* be found by going up, then you know you've marked the right path, and can return true. If a path can't be found by going up, then you know that going up isn't the right direction, so you check another direction. If after checking all directions, and you still haven't found a path, you know that you are on the wrong path, so you set `maze[r][c]` back to `' '` and return false.

```
private static boolean findPath(char[][] maze, int r, int c) {

    // Base Case #1: If Current Cell == 'H'
    if(maze[r][c] == 'H') {
       return true; // Stop Recursion, Conclusion: Path Found from 'G' to 'H'
    }

    // (Your other base cases are covered by the last "return false" statement) 

    // Recursive Cases:
    if(maze[r][c] == ' ') { // Check If Current Cell == ' '
        maze[r][c] = '^';
        if (findPath(maze, r-1, c)) {
            return true;
        }
        maze[r][c] = 'v';
        if (findPath(maze, r+1, c)) {
            return true;
        }
        maze[r][c] = '>';
        if (findPath(maze, r, c+1)) {
            return true;
        }
        maze[r][c] = '<';
        if (findPath(maze, r, c-1)) {
            return true;
        }
        maze[r][c] = ' ';
    }
    return false; // If End of Method Reached. Therefore, Hansel Hasn't Been Found Yet
}
```

Example usage:

```
char[][] maze = {
    "#####H#####".toCharArray(),
    "#G# # # # #".toCharArray(),
    "# # # # # #".toCharArray(),
    "# # # # # #".toCharArray(),
    "#         #".toCharArray(),
    "###########".toCharArray(),
};
boolean hasPath = findPath(maze, 1, 1);
System.out.println(hasPath);
for (char[] row : maze) {
  System.out.println(row);
}
```

Output:

```
true
#####H#####
#v# #^# # #
#v# #^# # #
#v# #^# # #
#>>>>^    #
###########
```

Note that my code assumes that the maze has walls or `H` all around. If your maze doesn't have that, you need to check that `c` and `r` are within the bounds of the 2D array first. If they are out of bounds, you should return false.

Comment: ahhh i see thank you very much but just quickly where you wrote
    // (Your other base cases are covered by the last "return false" statement) 
could you explain that i like i understand that its true but an in-depth explanation bcuz im supposed to have them there as base cases...like uh i mean im supposed to mark a period if i hit a dead end or something and go back and run it and eventually block up the incorrect path.... i havent gotten there yet but something like that i assume thats another recursive case...sorry if i worded things weird

Comment: @JohnDao What I mean is, the checks for `#` and `.` are redundant, because if `maze[r][c]` is `#` or `.`, the last `return false` will be hit anyway even if you don't check for `#` and `.` explicitly. If you need to do something special when a `.` is encountered, that's another question. Try doing it yourself first, and if you are stuck, post another question and state clearly what you want to do and show your attempts.

Comment: ohh ok i understand that now, though it is redundant would it be ok to keep? once again thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnDao Yeah you can keep it and the code will still work, but it is unnecessary.

Comment: ok thank you, do you have a suggest comment for the line
    maze[r][c] = ' ';
after having checked all the directions

Comment: @JohnDao we checked all the directions, and there is no path to H anywhere from (c, r), so clearly it is wrong to mark it with one of the arrow characters, so we erase the mark we put on it when we were checking the 4 directions.